# Unknown NullPointerException in Slick2D

Tags: java

I am trying to understand the basics of making a game in Slick2D. I have 4 classes: [Main](http://pastebin.com/338jdiL9), [Entity](http://pastebin.com/eTWenvzf), Misc (pastebin.com/e5WqF6Ma) and Fish (pastebin.com/ie0ANxxx)

Whenever I run the code, this is the console log.

```
Mon Aug 17 00:15:07 BST 2015 INFO:Slick Build #237
Mon Aug 17 00:15:07 BST 2015 INFO:LWJGL Version: 2.9.3
Mon Aug 17 00:15:07 BST 2015 INFO:OriginalDisplayMode: 1366 x 768 x 32 @60Hz
Mon Aug 17 00:15:07 BST 2015 INFO:TargetDisplayMode: 640 x 480 x 0 @0Hz
Mon Aug 17 00:15:08 BST 2015 INFO:Starting display 640x480
Mon Aug 17 00:15:08 BST 2015 INFO:Use Java PNG Loader = true
Mon Aug 17 00:15:08 BST 2015 INFO:Controllers not available
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com..prototypes.project_blueberry.util.Misc.addID(Misc.java:24)
    at com..prototypes.project_blueberry.util.Entity.<init>(Entity.java:16)
    at com..prototypes.project_blueberry.entity.Fish.<init>(Fish.java:15)
    at com..prototypes.project_blueberry.Main.init(Main.java:56)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:393)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:317)
    at com..prototypes.project_blueberry.Main.main(Main.java:44)
```

I have taken out some bits off stuff I don't want online, but the majority of stuff is there.

I have tried to troubleshoot the code, but I just can't figure out what is causing the exception. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Is Misc.java your class? I would want to know what's happening at line 24...

Comment: @bn. I have put a pastebin in the OP, but I couldnt use hyperlinks because I can only put 2 per post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you haven't initialize the integer array in Misc.java class. If you need to store values into a integer array then you have to initialize it with a given size.

```
private static int[] ids = new int[10];
```

Comment: how would I know what size to put? it is meant to be an entity system so I need it to be effectively infinite. Can I change the size?

Comment: Arrays can only used if the size if known. Otherwise you have to use a different data structure like ArrayList<Integer>, but again you have to initialize first.

Comment: hmm... What would I use if I want to use a random generator that spawns large amounts of instances of the class?

Comment: As in, an entity that will spawn, move around a bit, and then get destroyed. Or am I doing this entity system all wrong?

Comment: Not sure about the question, but if you need to destroy any object you can remove the reference by setting the `ids = null` and garbage collector will remove it from the memory.

Comment: well, I'm making a game, and I want to have some sort of system of keeping track of multiple entities (instances of the same class), and I was wondering what sort of thing you would recommend.

Comment: There are two cases, if you adding elements to a specific location (loc) then you should be using LinkedList and if you adding elements to the end, appending elements then you should use ArrayList. You can expect better performance over using those data structures.